# Proving that a function admits a primitive in a specific set?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{(z^2 - 1)(z^2 - 4)}$$

admits a primitive in the set $\{|z| > 4 \}$

I know that the only singularities of $f(z)$ are poles that occur at the points $z = 1, -1, 2, -2$, so in the set, so the set $\{|z| > 4\}$ contains no singularities... but I can't seem to come up with the precise reasoning to why it admits a primitive.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Find one?${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

A holomorphic function $f$ admits an anti-derivative on the domain $\Omega$ if and only if
$$
\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 0
$$
for all closed curves $\gamma \subset \Omega$.

In your particular case, a closed curve either winds around none of the poles $\pm 1, \pm 2$ in which case Cauchy's integral theorem guarantees that the corresponding integral vanishes **or** it winds an equal number of times around the poles. So the question boils down to whether the sum of the residues at $\pm 1, \pm 2$ is zero or not. I will leave this last verification to you. (It can be done, for example, by direct computation of the four residues in question, or by computing the integral along a huge circle.)